# How to get IMEI on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, imei

I want to get IMEI on iPhone. I try to use the following code:

```
#import "Message/NetworkController.h"
NetworkController *ntc=[[NetworkController sharedInstance] autorelease];
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];
```

But NetworkController is not found.

I also find that I can get uniqueIdentifier using:

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *identifier = myDevice.uniqueIdentifier;
```

But this cannot help me to get IMEI.

How to get IMEI on iPhone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't get IMEI on iPhone anymore. You may have to use UDID instead. See other answers.

---

In the past, you could use the header  file "Message/NetworkController.h" posted on ericasadun.com.
http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/_network_controller_8h-source.html (It's been removed now)

You would add the NetworkController.h file and the private framework "Message.framework" to your project, then import that header file to use the original method I found to get the imei number:

```
NetworkController *ntc = [NetworkController sharedInstance];
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];
```

That hack doesn't work anymore. App will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: Erica has posted a new way to get IMEI here: http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m

Comment: No, it's a private framework on iOS3. There's no need to use it now coz erica has posted a new way of getting imei.

Comment: @iPhoney Have you tried to use Erica's code and submit app to Apple? Just wonder if it will get approved or not. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. I also want to know if it will be banned by apple

Comment: I also want to know if it will be banned by apple or not, thanks

Comment: @Mighter: What doesn't work on iPhone 4S, the code in the answer or the code on GitHub in the first comment?

Comment: @iPhoney - application is crashing while getting imei, i am doing like this NSLog(@"%@",[UIDevice currentDevice].imei);

Comment: @Rajneesh071 have you got any solution to get IMEI number, even using private frameworks.. even i tried with these libraries, its crashing when i use that line of code..

Answer (score 7):

You can't find the IMEI programmatically on the iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official way to get it, but in Apples private framework `CoreTelephony.framework` there is a method `CTGetIMEI` that might help you.

Comment: I am using CoreTelephony frame in one of the apps. But unable to figure out how I can use __CTGetIMEI functions to get the IMEI number of the iPhone? Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are reasons you can't do this easily. Auto-unlocker app? I don't think so. I'm sure Apple and AT&T wouldn't like it too much either.

*#06# is the way to get it manually.

Comment: what is #06# ? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: dialing *#06# on all cell phones that I know of will show their IMEI.
That's star-hash-zero-six-hash.

Answer (score 2):

I made a search only here in stackoverflow and the conclusion is that Apple dont allow anymore to find phone EMEI after iOS 6.

You can identify a device using UDID.
I found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927376/2283308

Answer (score 1):

add a head file "CoreTelephony.h" to your project

CoreTelephony.h

```
struct CTServerConnection
{
    int a;
    int b;
    CFMachPortRef myport;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;
};

struct CTResult
{
    int flag;
    int a;
};

struct CTServerConnection * _CTServerConnectionCreate(CFAllocatorRef, void *, int *);

void _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileIdentity(struct CTResult *, struct CTServerConnection *, NSString **);
```

add the following code to your class

```
#import "CoreTelephony.h"

struct CTServerConnection *sc=NULL;
struct CTResult result;
void callback() { }
```

now, you can get imei easily

```
    NSString *imei;
_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileIdentity(&result, sc, &imei);
```

Comment: does not work for me when I test it on iPhone simulator (returns empty) is that expected ?

Comment: Please test this on real iPhone, I tested this on iPhone4 ,ios5.1.1

Comment: no, apple wont accept this. i found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19927376/2283308

Answer (score 0):

https://www.telesign.com/products/phone-id

There is an SDK by a company called TeleSign that can get a device's IMEI number (in addition to a list of other things such as carrier, the home address of the device's owner, etc.). Some of the biggest apps in the store use this provider (like Tinder and Evernote). I don't work for the company or ever have, or ever want to, and I've never used any of their products. I also don't know if Apple would reject this API usage. But if you want a Swift/Objecive-C interface for getting an IMEI number, this is one.