# How do I obtain the iPhone International Mobile Equipment Identity programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, imei

calling `#*06#` tells the IMEI ( [International Mobile Equipment Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) ) of the device.
I checked [International Numbering Plans](https://www.numberingplans.com/?page=analysis&sub=imeinr) and found out that this actually is the IMEI number.

Is it possible to obtain it programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get device IMEI programmatically. However UIDevice class has "unique device identifier" property.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *uniqueIdentifier
```

> A unique device identifier is a hash value composed from various hardware identifiers such as the device’s serial number. It is guaranteed to be unique for every device but cannot publically be tied to a user account. You can use it, for example, to store high scores for a game in a central server or to control access to registered products. The unique device identifier is sometimes referred to by its abbreviation UDID.

Comment: but i want to get IMEI, how to do this?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone. But it seems all solutions mentioned use private api, so you won't be able to use them if you want to release your app on AppStore