# IMEI number using iphone code

Tags: iphone, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

how can i get IMEI code from iphone simulator?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's not something you can do with the iPhone SDK.

You can get the iPhone/iPod's Unique Device Identifier (UDID), but not the IMEI, Serial or phone number.

Comment: i doubt that the simulator even has an IMEI somewhere... what would it be needed for?

Comment: You're correct, the simulator has no IMEI, only a physical iPhone would have one. iPods won't have one either, which is probably why there's no access to it.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated - you cannot get IMEI through public API. If you want to obtain some device identifier to use in your application you must use `uniqueIdentifier` property defined in `UIDevice` class - it is there for exactly that purpose.

```
NSString* uniqueID = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

FYI, you can obtain IMEI using private frameworks - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone), but your app will be rejected from app store then.

Answer (score 0):

IMEI is an HW code of each phone. You can get phones' IMEI typing: *#06*.
In iPhone simulator there is no IMEI.

Comment: actually its *#06# to get the IMEI no manually on the iphone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible - besides which, Apple will moan if you publish software which does that on the AppStore...