# How to get IMEI number from iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

I can get the UDID number but I want to get IMEI number...Is the apple dont allow to trace? If so where i can find the document of apple?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone/823326) is the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *imei = [[NetworkController sharedInstance] IMEI];
```

Comment: Can you please give more information on this.... How can i maintain NetworkController and all...