# Get IMEI of iPhone 4 (IOS 4.2)

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

Is it possible to get IMEI of iPhone 4 (IOS 4.2) via SDK ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check here: [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

According to one of the comments, [this is erica's latest code](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m) to retrieve the IMEI.