# How to get imei and serial number in iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

How to get imei number and serial number programmatically on iPhone?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the similar questions...?

Comment: i saw it and use it but not work because not have a NetworkController so error NetworkController is not found. i want a "Message/NetworkController.h" file

Comment: The comments in the accepted answer say how to solve this.

Comment: plz give a link of "Message/NetworkController.h" file and how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code here: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m. I think that gives you what you want.

Comment: i use that code but i got error IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty referenced from how to solve this