# Do application have access to all data on smartphone

Tags: android, ios, security, smartphone, sandbox

I would like to know if applications (iOS, Android or Blackberry) have access to all data on the phone or if there is a sandbox system preventing application from getting sensitive informations. I know an app can access pictures, contacts information or GPS locations but can  it access information like IMEI or IMSI numbers or else.

Thanks

Comment: I flagged your question as too broad -- I would suggest to search SO for specific answers on what you need, there should be enough information for what you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what data do you want.

For example, in Android you can get the IMEI as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android), and in iOS as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone).

Yet an application on unrooted device may not access another application's private data, and an iOS application has the application directory defined as its root, so it may not access other data as well.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for iOS, but in android you can get information like IMEI, provided the app has the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

E.G. to get the IMEI:

```
String imei = android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMEI);
```

To get the IMSI

```
String imsi = android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI);
```

*edit*

This is possible on iOS as well, something along the lines of:

```
NetworkController *ntc = [NetworkController sharedInstance];
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];
```

Comment: Is it possible to get IMSI on IOS?

Comment: Maybe, see this: http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=64

Answer (score 1):

You can find good things on Android website about security, private data and permissions on Android apps :
 [Android Security, Permission, Data](http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html)