# Get IMEI Numer from iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

How can I get the IMEI from an iPhone programmatically?

Is there a framework I have to add to my project?

Comment: Please search before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+imei

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *imeinumber = [[NetworkController sharedInstance] IMEI];
```

Comment: You might want to add that this is from a private framework. (See the question Unknown linked to in his/her answer.)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get IMEI through public API. If you want to obtain some device identifier to use in your application you must use uniqueIdentifier property defined in UIDevice class - it is there for exactly that purpose.

```
NSString* uniqueID = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

you can obtain IMEI using private frameworks - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone), but your app will be rejected from app store then.

Comment: `[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated

Comment: No apple can't reject If u do not use obtain IMEI. Read apple document.

Comment: i'm also get uniqueID and ran it my app, and now my app currently in appsotre. u read carefully. ok.

Comment: Sorry, bad link: http://www.websitemagazine.com/content/blogs/posts/archive/2012/04/03/bypassing-apple-s-rejection-of-udid-apps.aspx

Comment: If u use NetworkController *ntc = [NetworkController sharedInstance]; 
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];  u will get ur imei of ur iphone. apple rejected a app of @nehasoni. Bcz this person using this code. So rejected by apple. If u use UniqueId of iphone, apple never reject the app. cool :)

Comment: Who is downvoting. what problem in my code.?