# How to get IMEI number programmatically in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

How to get `imei` number from iPhone programmatically?

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question. Please make sure to search before you ask. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have some difficult get the IMEI number programatically. However, if you're looking for a way to identify a particular phone, you can use the UDID (Unique Device Identifier) to do so.

```
 NSString *UDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

and also try this for IMEI

```
NSString *imei = [[NetworkController sharedInstance] IMEI];
```

Comment: what is NetworkController?

Comment: Does it work for iOS 7?