# How to get IMEI number programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, imei

I try to get the IMEI number of the iDevice, i already found out how, but it wont work, I am using this method https://github.com/cheetahray/IMEI , the UIDevice-IOKitExtensions thing, I get errors. Can someone please tell me how to use it?

I got the info from [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

Comment: @Olli Charlesworth yeah, but i dont know why I get this errors, can you take a look on it?

Comment: The other question is 3 years old, so it's completely outdated. You're aware that a program using such an interface can't go into the App Store, and Apple forbids identifying a device anyhow? Why do you need this?

Comment: This is not for the AppStore, it is for Cydia and for alternative appstores. So can you help me?

Comment: What are the errors you receive?

Comment: Some .h files cant be fount, i dont know how to solve this