# get IMEI on iPhone with CoreTelephony?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-privateapi, imei

I have tried the accepted answer of 
[How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)
but I got an empty string.

I saw somebody suggested to use CoreTelephony framework,
but I am not sure how to use it to obtain the IMEI.

Any suggestion on how to use this private API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE: this does not work anymore!**

**Haven't tested on any new iOS.**

You have to add CoreTelephony.h to your project. 
Make sure the header has

```
int * _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo (
                                              struct CTResult * Status,
                                              struct __CTServerConnection * Connection,
                                              CFMutableDictionaryRef * Dictionary
                                              );
```

Then you can try this code:

```
#import "CoreTelephony.h"
void getImei() {
struct CTResult it;
CFMutableDictionaryRef kCTDict;
conn = _CTServerConnectionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, ConnectionCallback,NULL);
_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo(&it, conn, &kCTDict);
NSLog (@ "kCTDict is %@", kCTDict);
CFStringRef meid = CFDictionaryGetValue(kCTDict, CFSTR("kCTMobileEquipmentInfoMEID"));
NSLog (@ "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoMEID is %@", meid);
CFStringRef mobileId = CFDictionaryGetValue(kCTDict,    CFSTR("kCTMobileEquipmentInfoCurrentMobileId"));
NSLog (@ "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoCurrentMobileId is %@", mobileId);
}
```

Here's the [CoreTelephony.h](https://github.com/entryleveldev/CoreTelephonyIMEI/blob/master/ImeiTest/CoreTelephony.h)

You can check my [example project](https://github.com/entryleveldev/CoreTelephonyIMEI).

Note: I don't think the code works on the simulator and your app might get rejected.