# How to get IMEI number using Phonegap in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, imei

I have to retrieve the IMEI number in iPhone using Phonegap and i don't know how to do that. Does apple supports retrieving of device IMEI number programmatically or Is there any plugin available to do that?
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for getting IMEI number

```
NetworkController *ntc = [NetworkController sharedInstance];
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];
```

Also check this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836900/get-imei-on-iphone-with-coretelephony)