# How to know if iPhone is in recovery mode from my App

Tags: objective-c, keychain, appdelegate, sfhfkeychainutils

All

I am working on an app where i m storing DeviceIdentifier in keychain(thanks to deprecated method in ios6 to fetch unique identifier all the time)for later use to identify that it is a allowed device to use app.

i am storing it in keychain , what i want to achieve is if device is in recovery mode or if someone restoring a backup i want to send request to the server to deactivate this device identifier which is stored in keychain, before keychain get deleted.

is it achievable or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

whenever the server communicates with the device, check if the device identifier exists in the keychain, if not, then send a call back to server asking to deactivate the device identifier from the server.

Comment: Hi anjani,if keychain is not their then how will i know which device identifier to deactivate(Device Identifier is in the keychain),as it was deleted because of it has been recovered/backup has restored.

Comment: you could map imei number with a device identifier on the server side.
when the device identifier is sent to the server, check if it is already mapped to an imei, if imei is found, update the device identifier for that imei by replacing the older device identifier. 
caution:getting imei number may not be allowed publicly.

Comment: to get imei: 
https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone

Comment: it is not allowed by apple to fetch imei number: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927160/finding-imei-number-using-objective-c