# Who bought my app

Tags: android, ios, app-store, windows-phone, google-play

I develop mobile cross-platform games (for iOS,Android and WP).
I want to know the email or the phone number of the people who bought my app from the iOS,Android or WP store, for using these informations  for authentication  purpose.

Waiting for your valuable comments and sugessions

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have that information unless people authorize you or give it to you.

Under no circumstances should you be able to get the information of the people who are buying your apps unless they opt into it and it’s made crystal clear to them that you are getting this information.

[This was in the news last year](http://www.zdnet.com/google-play-privacy-slip-up-sends-app-buyers-personal-details-to-developers-7000011249/) because you **shouldn't** have that data.

This counts for iOS and Android.

**options**

- Ask users for their personal information in the app and send it to
  your servers.
- Make your app need registration and login ( This is very strict on iOS, make sure you have some kind of offerable service which actually need registration)

*You can link their personal information with device numbers, but these are spoofable on rooted and jailbroken devices*

To get the device information on android:

You want to call [android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()](http://www.zdnet.com/google-play-privacy-slip-up-sends-app-buyers-personal-details-to-developers-7000011249/).

This will return whatever string uniquely identifies the device (IMEI on GSM, MEID for CDMA).

You'll need the

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

permission to do this.

On iOS look at this answer: [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

Comment: Thanks, Can i get the device number(IMEI), before the user install my application.

Comment: No because your application is the only thing to get that information. edited post on how

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for **iOS**:
You can't get email address nor phone number using iOS APIs.  If you want this, you need to ask the user yourself.

Then you'd need a way to verify them:

- **Email** by sending a link they need to click.
- **Phone number** by sending the user an SMS (with link they need to click, or code they need to type in UI), or by calling them and asking them to dial/DTMF a code they see in the app, or on the app enter a code they hear.

If you want to keep users apart, without needing any info from them:

- Have a [non-consumable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2) in-app payment item (which you could call 'account' for example).  Since these items can only be bought once per user, and because Apple's in-app purchase receipt contains a unique ID, you can use this as a user identifier.  (If this does not make sense, you need to read Apple's documentation about in-app purchases.)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the final point,can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the user for mail/no then just store temperorly and use webservice to retrive in background

If you want the details without knowing to user Use analytics and catch maild id's of user (flurry , google analytics)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible currently. The playstore console displays information like number of download, carriers, devices, etc. You may want to consider building in those features and requesting the info from the user via the valid permissions. Aside there is an unofficial playstore API that lets you pull data viz. app info, comments, etc. You can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)