# Get IMEI and serial number from SIM on iOS programatically

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, iokit, imei

I need to get the IMEI number and serial number of the SIM card in iOS, i have done this in android using the telephonymanager, but how can i achieve this on iOS?

I need this value because I save it in a data base using a web service, each time a client attemp to log in, so it doesnt matter if the client changes celphone or not, the account will be the same because the SIM card will be the same one.

I have been searching on the web, and found a way with this:

```
NetworkController.m
```

But it seems like this class has been removed from the web. Another possible way to achieve my goal is to use:

```
UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m
```

But no documentation is given. Any ideas?

Does apple accepts an app using private framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get IMEI on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone)

Comment: This has been asked before. The short answer is that you can only do this with private frameworks (and `NetworkController` uses private frameworks).

Comment: Does apple accepts an app using private framework?

Comment: Is there any private API to get SIM SERIAL NUMBER?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple does not allow the use of private framework / api. Also, getting the users IMEI number will cause Apple to reject the app.

Comment: Is there any other way of getting an unique id of a SIM card in iOS?

Comment: Nope. Apple are trying hard to stop 3rd party developers getting this sort of information. They also stopped the use of UDIDs in iOS6 I believe.

Comment: I can get in ios7:
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[device identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

Comment: Sure - try submit that to the store and watch it get rejected.

Comment: There is no point of implementing IMEI if apple store doesnt admit it

Comment: identifierForVendor won't get your app rejected - it is the approved way of obtaining a unique device identifier - however, the identifier is unique for your apps (apps using the same bundle id get the same value) but can change if all of the apps from a vendor are deleted and one is subsequently re-installed and is different to the identifier that another app with a different bundle is will get on the same device.

Comment: You are welcome. There is another identifier which can be used for advertising, but misuse of that *will* get you rejected - you need to honour the add tracking preference of the user and not use it for non-ad related things

Comment: So identifierForVendor allows you get get an unique ID - until app is removed / reinstalled, and if installed on same iDevice - will be different to last ID obtained?

Comment: Lets put an example, if i have 10 iphones and I download and install the same "x" app on them from the app store, all this 10 iphone will have the same identifierForVendor value???

Comment: What i need is some unique number or string that identifies the device

Comment: Each one of the 10 iphones will have an unique identifier, and if they install another app developed by you, they will have the same identifier in both apps